# Borders only on the content of a full height container with a sticky footer layout

Tags: html, css, layout, sticky-footer

Hello guys this has been bugging me for hours.

Im using the layout to get full height containers and sticky footers.
Unfortunately i only want a border in the content but it is not extending to the footer.
I can try to give the the wrap div the borders but **i dont want the header to have borders.**
The only thing i can think of is giving the **header the border color of the background** but i dont want to do this.

Is there another way you can do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/VNc33/14/

```
    <body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <header>
            <img src="http://placedog.com/400/50" />
        </header>
        <div class="content">i dont want the header tag to have a border
      </div>
        <footer>This is a footer.</footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI0XV.jpg)

Comment: do u mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/VNc33/3/

Comment: i believe i mentioned that i only want the border in the "content" area

Comment: maybe you should rework your template, it breaks/hide content if filled :)  http://jsfiddle.net/VNc33/10/

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franvarn/VNc33/15/)

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <header>
            <img src="http://placedog.com/400/50" />
        </header>
        <div class="content">i dont want the header tag to have a border</div>
        <footer>This is a footer.</footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

--

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.wrap {
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:100%;
    background:lightblue;
}

header {
    height:8%; /* height can be anything but header + content + footer heights must be 100% or the page will scroll */
    border:0;
}

.content {
    height:84%;
    color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    /* keeps height at 84% instead of 84% + 2px for border */
}

footer {
    height:8%;
    background:darkred;
    color:white;
}
```

<strike>Change .wrap min-height to just height and add height:100% to .content</strike>

Comment: im sorry but i tried that and the content area extended below the footer

Comment: Does the footer have to be 50px? What about the header?

Comment: ^ changed the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

you can use an `inset` unblur box shadow on `.wrap`, so it should not bother much your layout :http://jsfiddle.net/VNc33/5/

```
.wrap {
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    min-height:100%;
    background:lightblue;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px;/* here fake an inside border of 1 pixel with text color if none declared */
}
```

`header { background:lightblue;/* background hides inset box-shadow from parent */}` http://jsfiddle.net/VNc33/8/ and you can remove borders from `.content` except the top one : http://jsfiddle.net/VNc33/9/ .

Comment: Unfortunately i do use box shadows in the website im working on and i dont really want it in the header.

Thanks for the answer anyway, im probably going to consider javascript

Comment: it is not in the header , (answer was updated), the inset shadow can be hidden by the background  of header. You can use multiple box-shadow as well : http://jsfiddle.net/VNc33/7/

Comment: yes i know what you meant but i dont want the box shadow (outset) in the header.

Comment: why outset ? when it is set inset ? i do not understand anymore what you look for :) .. be back in a couple of hours

Comment: i dont want the box shadow in the header

Comment: it is not if header has an inherited/same background of parent. ............................  Beside your basic template is breaking if you add content to it. there's many possibilities to have a basic template with a sticky footer: you can use display:table-row, calc(), position, box-sizing, fausse colonne method, etc ... , once you have a solid template, border drawn or added in .content area will be simple.

Answer (score 0):

With another CSS approach to build your fullHeight template , you can have header and footer of variable height, using the display properties used by  tags . (`<footer>` inside `.wrap`)

this method is avalaible in IE from version 8 , lower version wwill ignore the display:table/table-row/table-cell propertie and wil use the default display.http://jsfiddle.net/VNc33/11/

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header {
    height:50px;
}
.wrap {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:400px;
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    background:lightblue;
}
.content {
    color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
}
footer {
    height:50px;
    background:darkred;
    color:white;
}
header img {
    vertical-align:top;/* or bottom  or display:block */
}
header,  footer {
    display:table-row;
}
.content {
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
    border:solid 1px solid;/* just put the border here */
}
```

easy way to apply the border to `.content`  and not mind about how much content is hold

Comment: Wow thanks for reminding me display table cells i forgot about this. If i remember correctly i stayed away from it because it broke my layouts or something. Thank you nice work.

Comment: I remember now why i dont use display:table because it was frowned upon most of the websites about html and css tutorials. If it is impossible to achieve my desired layout without it, i have no choice but to use it.